# Formula to find the derivative of products of functions - Can anyone validate?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis

First of all, I wanted to mention that I'm a mechanical engineering student who is delving into pure mathematics and physics. I would like to share with you a formula for calculating the derivative of any product of functions (though I'm not sure if I should call it a proof). Since this is the first 'proof' I've attempted outside of textbook exercises, and I am new to this field, I would appreciate your feedback to verify its correctness (as I haven't found it anywhere). Thank you very much.

\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)
&=e^{\ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\right)} \\
&=e^{\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(f(x_i))} \\
&\approx e^{\int_1^n\ln(f(x))~\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align*}

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}: \quad e^{\int_1^n\ln(f(x))~\mathrm{d}x}\ln(f(n))$$

Edit: I made an error in the notation. Thank you to everyone who pointed it out

Comment: The line $\sum_{i=1}^n \ln f(x_i)\approx \int_1^n \ln f(x_i)\mathrm dx_i$ makes no sense. You are trying to integrate over an integer index.

Comment: For starters, don’t you need $f_i(x)$ rather than $f(x_i)$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: What does your rule say when $n=1$ and you are just differentiating one function? What about two?

Answer (score 5):

The usefulness of something like this is nebulous at best, but at minimum there is a critical flaw:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^{\int_1^n \ln(f(x_i)) \, \mathrm{d}x_i}
\ne \ln(f(x_i)) e^{\int_1^n \ln(f(x_i)) \, \mathrm{d}x_i}
$$
This is the result of several misunderstandings around the fundamental theorem of calculus.

- Firstly, you're differentiating with respect to $x$, not $x_i$ nor $n$: since your expression has no dependence on $x$, the derivative really should just be zero.
- If you mean to differentiate with respect to $x_i$, you can't do that either; its role is already fulfilled as that of a dummy variable for the integration. That is, more simply, the expression
  $$
  \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x) \, dx
  $$
  is nonsensical. Even if it had a well-defined meaning, the integral is not a function of $x$, so you would still more reasonably conclude zero as the derivative.
- If you want to differentiate with respect to anything for this to make sense, it would be $n$. Note that, however, the chain rule would give us $\ln(f(n))$ as the outside factor, not $\ln(f(x_i))$.

Some other problems of note, though I'm sure there are more that could be pointed out:

- Another error of note is at the outset, because
  $$
  \frac{d}{dx_i} \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
  $$
  (perhaps the only meaningful thing you could think you'd want to calculate, given your work) is also nonsensical. $x_i$ is defined via, in part, by the running index in the product: $x_i$ is meaningless outside that product.
- Note, that the $f(x_i)$ do not represent distinct functions, but the same function evaluated at different values $x_i$.
- Additionally, as noted in the comments, it does not make sense to have your approximation
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(f(x_i)) \approx \int_1^n \ln(f(x_i)) \, dx_i
  $$
  The $x_i$ already have a defined role in this problem, so it would be more correct to say
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(f(x_i)) \approx \int_1^n \ln(f(x)) \, dx
  $$
  (Regardless, this is also where I feel an attempt at an approximation like this is very useless, because this is a very coarse approximation.)
- If you want to get used to deriving formulas and proofs, that's great, but you should also make sure they make sense. I imagine several of the issues with this derivation would have been made immediately apparent if you had tried out your formula on a basic example.

If I must be blunt, a lot of these misunderstandings really suggest to me that you need to review your basics for functions, integration, and differentiation, if you're considering a STEM career path.

---

The only sensible thing vaguely within the parameters you're looking at is the product of $n$ functions, i.e.
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x)
$$
This is something well-known, and its formula follows from an induction proof. To save you the research, though,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x)
= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{df_i}{dx} \cdot \prod_{\substack{1 \le j \le n \\ i \ne j}} f_j \right)
$$
A generalization to arbitrarily-many differentiations is also known. More info is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule).

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate that you take some time to answer. I made the corrections on the notation, thanks for pointing it out! Have a nice day!